# JS, let x = (Math.random()*2|0) output explanation

Tags: javascript, random

Hello and thanks for stopping by.

I am still green behind the ears and I'm trying to understand the output of this code.

```
let x = (Math.random()*2|0)
```

It basically gives either 0 or 1. Why is that?

Is it because the random * 2 is sometimes rounded up to 1?
And how does `|` work here? Is it considered like a OR? `||`

The original code I found:

```
var randomNum = ((Math.random () * 2 | 0) + 1) - 1;
```

Is there any difference?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: there is no difference in the result, but superfluous adding and subtracting of the same value.